# image to text to image with fade out/in on multiple images

Tags: jquery, image, html, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to make my index page have 10 images, with each image when mouseovered it will fade in to a paragraph of text then when moused out will fade back to the original image.

Each image is different of the 10 (its a portfolio), with different contents of text.

I am a completely jQuery n00b and below is my current html page.

So far I have figured out how to get a single image to fade into another image but haven't managed to find an easy way to have 10 images on the index page do this at different times (e.g. when an image is moused over) nor have I figured out how to get the image to change into text rather then another image... help please.

Any suggestions or code is very much appreciated..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
img {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
</style>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script TYPE="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#imgs')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('#i2').fadeOut('slow');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('#i2').fadeIn('slow');
    });  
});

</script>

</head>
<body>


<div id="imgs">
    <img src="/images/unlimited.jpg" id="i1">  <!-- this is the mouseover image -->
    <img src="/images/optimize.jpg" id="i2">  <!-- this is the default image -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```